# Data source workflow action in SXA

Tags: sxa, workflow

I am trying to use [Assign a data source workflow action](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/100/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/assign-a-data-source-workflow-action-in-sxa.html) in SXA feature in SXA 10 so that when a page move in a workflow all data sources have a states updates as well and create new version on each data source
I duplicate the sample workflow and added my action , I assigned the workflow to a page , however I've noticed the date source item workflow states does not change

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you verify what rules are set in the Interactive section of the Datasource Workflow Action?

Comment: Have you updated Command Items in Command Item respectively to new workflow? Aren't you referencing the workflow commands from copied sample workflow?

Comment: You might be experiencing this: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/26895/how-does-the-sxa-datasource-workflow-work

Comment: i added more screenshots , there is no rules assigned and even tried on the default workflow but still not working for me based on link shared by Gatogordo , dose that mean the datasource item will move need to set manually every time , and then what is the use  of this feature

Comment: @user1534066 You know that you need to manually assign your custom "data source workflow" to your data source items, right?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old issue but I thought someone else might stumble across this question:

**Sitecore 10.3**

I just had this issue myself and I've finally got it working.. classic sitecore documentation being misleading.

So what you've got setup looks correct, but on the datasource template set the workflow default workflow to also use Workflows/Sample Workflow.
the Datasource Workflow Action uses the states to move the datasource items along the workflow.  I haven't disassembled the DLLs to 100% confirm how it works but my testing shows it working now.

To test it:

1. Login to CM as an editor and edit the page with a Promo added (using a datasource)
2. Submit the changes
3. In another browser, log in with admin and you'll see both page and datasource item is now in approval mode.  If you approve the Page changes, the datasource item will be approved in the same process.

Hopefully, this helps!  I'll come back to this ticket when I've had a chance to disassemble the DLLs and confirm what is actually happening under the hood